# Php 404's after moving site

Tags: php, mysql

I inherited one PHP site recently which I had to move to another account on same hosting. I made exact copy of the site and environment, exported and imported all databases and script gets through to them. I had to change MySQL settings in `_cfg.php` for that matter.

But despite index page loading well, building itself with database links and such, I can't get anything except it. Every link giving me 404 in logs and same index page renders in browser. Links are present in this way: `mysite/index.php?page=info&pid=279`

I wonder where to start with this problem. I suspect that there may be some variable that needs change, but full-text search on source code with old domain name didn't bear a fruit.

Comment: Is the site using an existing Content Management System (e.g. Joomla), or is it custom-made?

Comment: I believe it doesn't even have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out the .htaccess file routes are consistent with the new folder.